# Java how to divide 2 doubles with 2 digits precision?

Tags: java

`amount / 100 * 7` - I'am trying to get a percent from an amount, but the problem is that sometimes a get a number with to many digits after dot, how can I make it strictly return 2 digits after dot?

type is double

Comment: it doesn't "return two digits". it returns a `double`, however many decimal digits worth of precision that would signify (14...16, IIRC). You may want to **format** your output, though.

Answer (score 1):

Use [DecimalFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) API

```
        double d = amount / 100 * 7;
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
        System.out.print(df.format(d));
```

"##" denotes the 2 digit precision

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
 double d = Math.round(amount * 7) / 100.0;
```

This will give you have value which has two decimal places. (for a modest range of values i.e. < 70e12)

If you just want to print two decimal places you can use

```
System.out.printf("%.2f%n", d);
```