# Why am I getting this precision error?

Tags: java

This is the code i am using to calculate a percentage and round it to 2 decimal places. However, at the moment, the result comes out as 45.0% rather than 45.33%

```
int one = 432;
int rolls = 953;

double test1 = 100 * one / rolls;
double finalValue1 = Math.round( test1 * 100.0 ) / 100.0;
```

Why are no decimal places showing?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2538787/how-to-display-an-output-of-float-data-with-2-decimal-places-in-java

Comment: The reason no decimal places are showing is because I'm fairly certain that Java will print the least number of decimals needed to express the `double`. In this case, 45.00 = 45.0, so Java will skip the extra decimal place and print the latter.

Comment: Yesterday, the **exact same question** was asked. Is it "round to 2 decimal places in Java assignment" time this week or what?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java how to divide 2 doubles with 2 digits precision?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23385867/java-how-to-divide-2-doubles-with-2-digits-precision)

Comment: I would argue that this is not a duplicate question. Yes if you look at just the title it is a duplicate question, but if you look at his question and his code, you'll notice that this is actually a precision error and not a formatting error. And this duplicate error is specific to this very case. OP should be guided to edit the title in his question. I've made an edit to the title.

Answer (score 1):

as you are multiplying integers the result of test1 is integer
so you have to say
`double test1= 100.0*one/rolls;` or
`double test1=(double)100*one/rolls`

Answer (score 0):

You could use String.format("%.2f",test1). If you use round, then java would round the the integer value.  Thus, formatting it this way would give you the answer you seek.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the following line:

```
double test1 = 100 * one / rolls;
```

That is because `100`, `one`, and `rolls` are of type `int`.

When you do `100 * one`, that will result in `43200`. Then, we have to execute the rest of the calculation... `43200 / 953` would actually equal `45.330535152`, but because these are both of type `int` the result will be `45`. Making `test1 = 45`. Since test one is a double, it will actually be `45.0`.

The next calculation, which uses `test1` will be off because of the above, resulting in "no decimal value".

To fix this, you can change the type of `one` and `rolls` to double.

Answer (score -2):

You have *two* problems.

First and foremost, you are performing **integer division**

```
double test1 = 100 * one / rolls;
```

`100`, `one` and `rolls` are all `int`. This means the result is an integer, regardless of what you've declared the return type to be. This is covered in the SO question [Why the result of 1/3=0 in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4685450/302916):

> the result variable as double just causes an implicit conversion to occur after division.

If you want `double`s, use doubles:

```
double one = 432.0;
double rolls = 953.0;
```

After fixing that, your division of `Math.round( test1 * 100.0 ) / 100.0;` will produce a `double`, but probably with more than two places of precision. It's unclear at that point if you want further rounding to a specific precision, but if you only wanted to print the two digits after the decimal you could use:

```
System.out.printf("%.2f", finalValue1);
```